# java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server

Tags: java, servlets, io

I am using a servlet which passes a String parameter to another Servlet in another remote system, to get xml response from that remote servlet.

This works fine when i tried to connect to that remote Servlet from my local PC.

But I am getting the error `java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server` when I execute same from another server.

Error:

```
2011-06-04 11:27:24,305 INFO  [STDOUT] strURL in Inventry --> http://1**.1**.**.27:7777/GatewayServlet
/Status?Str=Inventory&PARTNUM=200A104%27%2C%27200A112%27%2C%27200A114%27%2C%27200A113%27%2C%27200A117%27%2C%27200A120%27%2C%27240A503%27%2C%27200A132%27%2C%27200A128%27%2C%27200A124
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR] java.net.SocketException: Unexpected end of file from server
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(Unknown Source)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(Unknown Source)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.cim.web.servlet.DBGatewayServiceServlet.processRequest(DBGatewayServiceServlet.java:52)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at com.cim.web.servlet.DBGatewayServiceServlet.doGet(DBGatewayServiceServlet.java:113)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
2    011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:179)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:262)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:446)
2011-06-04 11:28:06,243 ERROR [STDERR]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Code in My Servlet (client):

```
if(queryString.equals("Inventory")) {

   String partNum = (String)session.getAttribute("PARTNUM");
   String locId = (String)session.getAttribute("locids");

   strURL = strURL+"/InventoryStatus?queryStr=Inventory&PARTNUM="+partNum;

   URLConnection dbGatewayURL = new URL(strURL).openConnection();

   BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(dbGatewayURL.getInputStream()));//--This is line 52 Mentioned in Error above

   StringBuffer responseData = new StringBuffer();
   String line="";

   while((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
      responseData.append(line);
   }

   String result =responseData.toString();
   request.setAttribute("inventryStock",result);

   RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher ("inventryStatus.jsp?resp=Yes");
   rd.forward(request, response);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with the code but the thing was the remote server wasn't listening to the connection from my server, hence i tried the same code but on another remote server this time and its working fine....! any body know the reason............?

Comment: Thanks, needed to add my server to the trusted hosts. Although it was for a SOAP based invocation, since my server was not in trusted hosts, I was getting similar trace

Answer (score 2):

Try to telnet to the remote servlet from your server and see whether it connects as expected. If it is not, then that's a connectivity issue.

If it does, try to use a TCP Monitor to see the HTTP traffic that goes from your server to the remote server which has the servlet. http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/

Answer (score 1):

try to wait() immediately after 
      URLConnection dbGatewayURL = new URL(strURL).openConnection();

It is possible the program moved to the next line **before** it was able to make the connection

Comment: well no luck.. made below change and got another exception: